# Entity Framework, posting an entity containing a collection of already existing entites

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

A bit of background, I have 2 tables in a database that share a many-to-many relationship through a junction table. Almost identical to the scenario outlined in [this blog post](http://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2010/06/29/entity-framework-queries-involving-many-to-many-relationship-tables/).

I will use a very simplified example of what I'm trying to do. When a user on my web app wants to create an Order, they have access to a list of Products to add to the order before posting. This list of products is fetched trough a REST api call and is made available to the client app as JSON data.

My problem arises when I post an Order, Entity frame work tries to **re-save** the Products in my collection rather that just create the association.

Consider the following extremely simplified code sample of my controller and my UnitOfWork class.

```
public class OrdersController : ApiController
{
   private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
   private readonly IOrderRepository _orderRepository;

   public OrdersController(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IOrderRepository orderRepository)
   {
       _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
       _orderRepository = orderRepository;
   }

   // POST api/Orders
   public Dto.Get.Order Post(Dto.Post.Order postOrder)
   {
       Models.Order modelOrder = new Model.Order();

       modelOrder.Name = postOrder.Name;
       modelOrder.Description = postOrder.Description;

       foreach (var getProduct in postOrder.Products)
       {
           Models.Product modelProduct = new Models.Product();

           modelProduct.Id = getProduct.Id;
           getProduct.Name = getProduct.Name;
           getProduct.Price = getProduct.Price;

           modelOrder.Products.Add(modelProduct);
       }

       modelOrder.AccountId = 999;

       _orderRepository.Insert(modelOrder);
       _orderRepository.Save();

       _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();

       //Return new Order as it exists in DB
       return Get(modelOrder.Id);
   }
}

public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
   public MyApplicationContainer Context { get; set; }

   public UnitOfWork(MyApplicationContainer context)
   {
       Context = context;
       this.Context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
       this.Context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
   }

   public void SaveChanges()
   {
       Context.SaveChanges();

   }

   private bool disposed = false;

   protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
   {

       if (!this.disposed)
           if (disposing)
               Context.Dispose();

       this.disposed = true;
   }

   public void Dispose()
   {
       Dispose(true);
       GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
   }
}
```

*Note: For simplicity, I didn't bother to post my Post and Get DTOs, or my Models for the Order and Product entities.*

One interesting observation, if I fetch the model version of the Product based on the incoming ID and then assign it to the collection to be saved, it works fine. But that seems very "chatty" to me, considering an Order could potentially have hundreds of Products. Example:

```
    foreach (var getProduct in postOrder.Products)
       {
          var modelProduct = _productRepository.Get(getProduct.Id);

           modelOrder.Products.Add(modelProduct);
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are explicitly creating a new product with the new operator. Obviously EF tries to create new products in the database. You need to query the database for the products but you should do it with one query. Something along the lines of

```
var productsIDs = postOrder.Products.Select(p => p.ID).ToArray();
var actualProducts = from p in product
                     where productsIDs.Contains(p.ID)
                     select p;
```